# Write Mysql tables to XML : Security Issue

Tags: php, xml, security

I want to make a news portal(php) with  minimum mysql force.
:create a cron, fetch data from mysql and write to a php file . (I dont know is it right way)
But Can I use xml instead of php file? Write mysql data to xml. 
Is this a secure way? What is the best way? XML or php file?

[alt text http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/4784/87392425.gif](http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/4784/87392425.gif)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `want to make a news portal(php) site with minimum mysql force` the  idea itself is quite stupid. Don't be a fool and don't change a database for a text file

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel; what is the meaning of "stupid"? 
I see that you have "none stupid" ideas. Can you please share this none stupid ideas with us?

Comment: Well, both *can* be done; but what do you intend to do with the (XML|php) file once it's written? Will the users of the site access it directly, or will there be some more processing before you send them data?

Comment: Database's intention to be used. Your expression is like "I want a car with minimum engine force". that's meaning of stupid.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel ; Its not stupid. But yet, I cant see your none stupid ideas. Or, maybe you have not any idea.

Comment: **don't change a database for a text file**. Hope now you can see

Comment: Unless the "text file" is sent to the client as-is, in which case we at least could _consider_ it as a caching mechanism.

Comment: I see no question about mysql optimization. So, there can be no answer. I hope you just forgot to turn your logic on. It's time. Any reason you want to use "minimum mysql force" ?

Comment: "I will show data from this txt to site with fonksiyons" - with what? Does this mean you'd have to process the data from the (flat) file prior to sending it to the client? How have you determined that MySQL is/will be the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel; For any idea, you can read the question "assiduous". Or forget it ;)

Comment: @VolkerK,
Does this mean you'd have to process the data from the (flat) file prior to sending it to the client?
 : yes

Comment: Oh and your question (especially 1st edition) of course is plain and clear. Try to look in a mirror.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel , you are here, I dont need a mirror :D

Comment: @jasmine: Sorry, I don't know what you mean; searching for "fonksiyons" finds about 8 pages in what I think is Turkish; is this some less-known programming framework?

Comment: That processing of the data of yours, does it include filtering, grouping, aggregation? Esp. that would mean that you'd try to implement features of a (relational) database ...in php. And then the question how you've determined the database to be the bottleneck becomes even more ... _interesting_ .

Comment: @jasmine @Col. Shrapnel Ooh, you two, get a room, will ya?

Comment: So, you cannot provide any reason.

Comment: @Piskvor Fonksiyon = function. Im sorry, I cant edit my comment. (I have to delete it)Piskover, its very very simple question 
mysql -> php or xml file -> Client 
@deceze, we two, dont want get a room yaaa !!!

Comment: "php or xml file" - what would you write to the .php file? php code generated by another php script? What would this generated php code do?

Comment: I dont ask this question for be convicted of an offense or answers with abusive language .
@VolkerK; I want to know is this way is right or not. 
mysql -> php or xml file -> Client
BTW, thanks for answers moreover in abusive language.

Comment: @jasmine Volker is exactly the wrong person to rail against in this thread, he's actually trying to help you, and rather politely at that. The problem is that your question doesn't make a lot of sense, so everybody here is trying to either clarify the question or show you that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: "I dont ask this question for be convicted of an offense or answers with abusive language" - Sorry, you're barking up the wrong tree.... "I want to know is this way is right or not." - And I think we need to know what you're actually trying to do before we can tell you if there is any chance for this to fly. You said "mysql -> php or xml file -> Client" but on the other hand you also said the data from the flat file needs processing, that would be "mysql -> php or xml file -on each request-> (what kind of?) **processing** -> Client". And esp. the processing part can easily ruin your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start of by saying that MySQL is very fast and very secure.  I recommend building the pages with MySQL upon request, most web applications do this because its a very good approach.   To save resources you can cache the output using a [Squid Reverse Proxy](http://www.visolve.com/squid/whitepapers/reverseproxy.php), and it is very common to see this on high traffic sites. PHP's APC will also reduce resource consumption without sacrificing secuirty. [Smarty's Caching system](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/caching.php) is also a good approach with minimal security impact.

There are secuirty concerns regardless of what method you choose,  but some approaches more hazardous than others.  For instance creating .php files with user input is probably the most dangerous thing you can attempt to do with a php web app.

```
$page='$title="'.$_GET['user_title'].'"';
file_put_contents("/var/www/page.php",$page);
```

An attack against this code would look like this:

```
http://localhost/page_creater.php?user_title='; eval($_GET[backdoor]); /*
```

Creating XML files with user input is also dangerous because it opens the door for [Advanced LFI Attacks](http://www.milw0rm.com/papers/260).  However,  the counter argument is that as long as your application is free from Local File Include vulnerabilities,  then you shouldn't have to worry.  But this is not a "Defense in-depth" design,  because you should plan on failure.

Its possible to implement something like Squid's reverse proxy [in php using ob_start()](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php),  however your still creating files with attacker controlled data,  and that is **hazardous**.   Also don't include() .html files that's incredibly stupid (See advanced LFI attacks...),  a better approach is this: `print(file_get_contents($file))`.  I do like using .html files over using .xml files because html doesn't have to be processed before outputting it to the user.  Using xml files as a data storage is wasteful of resources when compared to MySQL.

(**Disclaimer:** Vulnerabilities have been found in Smarty and squid, and php, and linux, and mysql and apache and.... everything else, even StackOverflow ;)